# Deleting column in devexpress grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I want to delete column in devexpress grid without using Customization window. For example: by dropping column out of grid or there will be a X button on column that will delete it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to drag-drop a particular ASPxGridView Column into the Customization Window or hide the Columns programmatically.
See the following Examples:

[E3812](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3812.aspx)

[E2023](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2023.aspx)

[E3031](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3031.aspx)

If you want to show/hide an individual Column while export, use the solution from the [E3352](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3352.aspx) Example.

Comment: Yes, I can use Customization Window, but I don't want as I mentioned. Then I want to export columns that are not hodden, so If I don't do it in 'natural way', then I will have problems with exporting columns (I save grid state in session). Thanks anyway :) +1